# Setting file permissions on contents of tarfile

Tags: unix, tar

Is there a way to `chmod 777` the contents of a tarfile upon creation (or shortly thereafter) before distributing?  The write permissions of the directory that's being tar'd is unknown at the time of tar'ing (but typically 555).  I would like the unrolled dir to be world writable without the users who are unrolling the tar to have to remember to `chmod -R 777 <untarred dir>` before proceeding.

The clumsy way would be to make a copy of the directory, and then `chmod -R 777 <copydir>` but I was wondering if there was a better solution.

I'm on a Solaris 10 machine.

**BACKGROUND:**

The root directory is in our ClearCase vob with specific file permissions, recursively. A tarfile is created and distributed to multiple "customers" within our org. Most only need the read/execute permissions (and specifically DON'T want them writable), but one group in particular needs their copy to be recursively writable since they may edit these files, or even restore back to a "fresh" copy (i.e., in their original state as I gave them).

This group is somewhat technically challenged. Even though they have instructions on the "how-to's" of the tarfile, they always seem to forget (or get wrong) the setting of the files to be recursively writable once untarred. This leads to phone calls to me to diagnose a variety of problems where the root cause is that they forgot to do (or did incorrectly) the chmod'ing of the unrolled directory.

And before you ask, yes, I wrote them a script to untar/chmod (specific just for them), but... oh never mind.

So, I figured I'd create a separate, recursively-writable version of the tar to distribute just to them. As I said originally, I could always create a copy of the dir, make the copy recursively writable and then tar up the copy dir, but the dir is fairly large, and disk space is sometimes near full (it can vary greatly), so making a copy of the dir will not be feasable 100% of the time.

Comment: you'll have to chmod the original source dir BEFORE you run tar. tar will capture the permissions/ownership at the time of tarring. There's options to force changing perms when extracted, but you can't expect users to remember those extra options.

Comment: Python has a nice `tarfile` library for writing custom tarring scripts, but GNU tar seems to have no option for this.

Comment: @MarcB I would then lose the existing permissions.

Comment: @larsmans I just dipped my toes into the Python waters a few days ago. I'll have to check this out.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

With GNU tar, use the `--mode` option when creating the archive, e.g.:

```
tar cf archive.tar --mode='a+rwX' *
```

But note that when the archive is extracted, the umask will be applied by default. So unless the user's umask is 000, then the permissions will be updated at that point. However, the umask can be ignored by using the `-p` (`--preserve`) option, e.g.:

```
tar xfp archive.tar
```

Comment: What is the significance of the uppercase `X`? I know `x` is normally the executable bit, but I've never seen it capitalized before.

Comment: @DrewChapin When setting permissions on all files in a directory, `a+x` should usually be avoided because it makes things executable that don't make sense (text files, config files, etc). `a+X` only makes files executable if they already have at least one execute bit set.

Comment: Is it also possible to set the permissions when packing under Windows, as that certain files are executable under Linux ootb?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change the permissions on the files prior to your tar command, although I generally recommend people NEVER use 777 for anything except /tmp on a unix system, it's more productive to use 755 or worst case 775 for directories.  That way you're not letting the world write to your directories, which is generally advisable.

Most unix users don't like to set the permissions recursively because it sets the execute bit on files that should not be executable (configuration files for instance) to avoid this they invented a new way to use chmod some time ago, called symbolic mode.  Reading the man page on chmod should provide details, but you could try this:

```
cd $targetdir; chmod -R u+rwX,a+rX .; tar zcvf $destTarFile .
```

Where your $targetdir is the directory you are tarring up and $destTarFile is the name of the tar file you're creating.

When you untar that tar file, the permissions are attempted to be retained.  Certain rules govern that process of course - the uid and gid of the owner will only be retained if root is doing the untaring, but otherwise, they are set to the efective uid and gid of the current process.

Comment: Even `/tmp` should be `1777` rather than just plain `777`; that prevents people who can't write to a file from deleting it (sticky bit on the directory).  But the best way is to set the permissions on the directories before creating the `tar` file.

Comment: (And, jokey aside, if you'd waited another day or so, you'd be eligible for a Revival badge if you get a second up-vote.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that would change the existing permissions on my files. This is undesirable, as I already mentioned in my reply to @MarcB.  I only want world read/write on the contents of the unrolled tar.

Comment: Fair enough @splungebob.  But my point still stands - why on earth would you want to do that?  Also, what's wrong with the way you have your own permissions set if you're taring it up to give to someone else?  An install script which you put in the root of your tarball could be used to set permissions and make sure everything is as you expect...  Would you like an answer detailing how to do that?

Comment: @CharlesBedford I edited the OP to include some background information.

Comment: Thank you for the improved clarity @splungebob :)  Yes the only way I can think of that is by copying your files elsewhere, and changing the permissions prior to your taring it up.  With that in mind, I like to use cpio sometimes for local copies... it's been faster on occasion and has been quite reliable - cd srcdir; cpio -pdmuv destdir